# Why should I use IAM roles?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

Please help me understand why AWS recommends assigning roles to EC2 instances ("role-based approach")
over storing API keys in files on the instance ("file-based approach")?

Consider three use cases:
(i) There is a 'tomcat' account on the instance which runs a web application. The application makes no use of AWS API.
There is another account ('support') on the instance which uses AWS API for housekeeping and maintenance
(logs, metrics etc).

With the file-based approach, if an attacker exploits the application and gets access to the filesystem (as 'tomcat'),
they won't be able to read the credential file (readable only by 'support') and won't be able to make AWS API calls.
The same is true if the attacker gets to execute arbitrary code under the 'tomcat' account.

However with the role-based approach, if an attacker gets access to the filesystem, they gain nothing
(as there is no credential file at all) and they cannot call AWS API. But if the attacker gets to execute arbitrary code
they may call the API.

(ii) There is a 'tomcat' account which runs a web application. The application calls AWS API for its operation.
There is also another account ('support') which uses AWS API for housekeeping and maintenance.
Both accounts need to access different resources (eg. 'tomcat' needs S3, while 'support' needs logs and metrics).

In the role-based approach, the role assign to the instance will effectively contain the union of the permissions
needed by 'tomcat' and 'support', which goes against the Least Priviledge principle. Even if the permissions were
technically divided between two role, each account will be ultimately able to assume a role it doesn't really need.

With the file-based approach, if an attacker gains access to the file system, they will be able to read 'tomcat'
credentials and make API calls from another machine (this could be avoided by restricting the policies
to a particular source IP, although it would be cumbersome to maintain). If the attacker gets to execute an arbitrary
code, they will be able to make API calls from the EC2 instance. In both cases, the 'support' account will remain
protected by the operating system.

With the role-based approach, if an attacker gains access to the file system, the gain nothing in terms of API calls,
as there is no credential file at all. However, if an attacker get to execute arbitrary code, they can make API calls
from the instace on behalf on BOTH roles ('tomcat' and 'support').

(iii) There is a 'tomcat' account which runs a web application. The application calls AWS API for its operation.
No other API calls are made from the instance.

With the file-based approach, if an attacker gains access to the file system, they will be able to read 'tomcat'
credentials and make API calls from another machine (this could be avoided by restricting the policies
to a particular source IP, although it would be cumbersome to maintain). If the attacker gets to execute an arbitrary
code, they will be able to make API calls from the EC2 instance.

With the role-based approach, if an attacker gains access to the file system, the gain nothing in terms of API calls,
as there is no credential file at all. However, if an attacker get to execute arbitrary code, they can make API calls
from the instance.

So it seems that the recommended role-based approach actually increases the risk in cases (i) and (ii).

What am I missing here?

Comment: I'd have to track down the actual AWS recommendation, but what I recall is that in conjunction with the EC2 role access, you should create iptables based roles that restrict access to 169.254.169.254 only to accounts who should have access to it, so in your scenario above, the 'tomcat' user wouldn't have access to 169.254.169.254, which would render the discovery of the ec2 IAM role credentials impossible for that user.

Comment: With a file based approach, unless you are using some other system to access and fetch/rotate credentials, your credentials are created once and never change, so if an actor got access to your credentials they would be good forever - if an actor got access to an ec2 instance and copied the access codes, they would only last for a lmited time

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/436086/how-to-prevent-firewall-calls-to-aws-ec2-instance-metadata-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have **multiple sets of users on the Amazon EC2 instance**, with each requiring different IAM permissions, then providing credentials by assigning an IAM role to the EC2 instance is not appropriate.

In general, it is recommended to use the Role method because credentials are not stored anywhere. Credentials stored on disk are sometimes accidentally checked into source-code repositories. They are also accessible to users who have the ability to create Snapshots of the disk volume, which they could then attach to other instances to access the configuration files and avoid normal security. This shows that it is also important to **use least privilege by only giving IAM Users the specific permissions they require for their job**, but not more.

Assigning roles to instances requires the `ec2:PassRole` permission, so this also has to be carefully granted to ensure users are not assigning themselves Roles that grant too much permission to access AWS services.

**Bottom line:** It is great that you have been thinking so much about security. Follow the process that you consider most appropriate for your business need.